# Discord.py - How would I get the ID of a Voice Channel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to get the ID of the author's voice channel. I'm trying to get it to make a link that you can click to go onto a full voice channel (if that makes sense):

```
@client.command()
async def fullv(ctx):

 guild=ctx.message.guild
 author=ctx.message.author
 channel = 
 vc=f"https://discordapp.com/{guild.id}/{channel.id}"

 embed=discord.Embed(title="Join Full Voice", url=vc, description="Full voice is a DM voice chat in a Discord Server!", color=0x00ff40)

 await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Without `{channel.id}` in `vc=f"https://discordapp.com/{guild.id}/{channel.id}"` it works fine but then you can't view the voice channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctx.author.voice` is the [`VoiceState`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState) of the author, which has a `channel` attribute representing the `VoiceChannel` that member is in:

```
if ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel:
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
else:
    await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel")
    return
```

Comment: That worked thanks! Now I just have to get it to open the link in Discord, I fixed the code so the link is correct (it was incorrect) but it opens the link in a new tab, whereas if it says the link without it being hyperlinked it works, if you know what I mean